# Angular2 application only works the first time

Tags: angular, systemjs

I have made a simple Angular2 component much like in the tutorial (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

This Angular2 component runs inside a modal in a larger application.

This is the content of the modal:

```html
<script>
    System.import('my-app')
</script>

<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

The application only works when opening the modal for the first time. When I clear the content and run `System.import('my-app')` again it does nothing (there is no error and the `<my-app>Loading... </my-app>` stays visible).

It works only after refreshing the page.

How do you start the same Angular2 module a second time?

Comment: Are you sure that script is running again? Can you reproduce a minimal sample of your application on the plunker?

Comment: @yurzui So what you are saying is that it *should* work when i ask SystemJS to import stuff it has already imported before?

Comment: I think that second import doesn't work. Maybe you need to use something like global function to run your angular2 application like window.fireNg2

Comment: See this example https://plnkr.co/edit/ewyuA0aR48EnBlUdbrQS?p=preview

Comment: It looks like the code that works is in the module initialization code. If so, it indeed will be executed only on the first import - the purpose of modules in general is to provide exports, not to run code.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the problem is that `my-app` does not expose any exports. I've had to adjust main.ts from:

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import MyAppModule from './my-app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyAppModule);
```

to

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import MyAppModule from './my-app.module';

export default function main() {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyAppModule);
}
```

And the init code from:

```html
<script>
    System.import('my-app');
</script>
```

to

```html
<script>
    System.import('my-app')
            .then(function(main) { 
                main.default();
            });
</script>
```

(promise catch code omitted for brevity)